# Cartesian list of files from separate folders

Tags: python, pandas

I have a directory with numerous folders in it, and I want to create a Cartesian list from all the files within each folder separately. So each folder would get its own Cartesian list.

I can do this for one folder like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os, glob, itertools

path =(r'C:\pathway')
allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
result = list(itertools.product(allfiles,allfiles))
```

I can loop through all the files in all the folders like this:

```
path =(r'C:\pathway') 

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files: 
        df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir,file))
```

but I am not sure how to make separate Cartesian lists for the files in every single folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply your method to all sub folders in your directory you can use the following code :

```
os.walk(<directory>)
y = next(os.walk('.'))[1]


directory = "/Users/bla/asd"
folders = os.walk(directory)
folders_arr = folders.next()[1]

results=[]
for folder_name in folders_arr: 
     path = directory + "/" + folder_name
     allfiles = glob.glob(path)
     results.append(list(itertools.product(allfiles,allfiles)))
```

Comment: this seems to make a Cartesian list of all folder names, what I am looking for is separate Cartesian lists of files within the folders.  So if there are 20 folders there would be 20 Cartesian lists

Comment: @stefanopotter, notice that i used 'results'  as list of lists (each element in results is a cartesian list of a single folder), so in your case the size of results should be 20.

Comment: you are correct, the number of items in results matches my number of folders, but I think I am overlooking something.  Each element in results is a pathway to the folders, how would I go about actually printing out the cartesian list of files within each of the elements in results?

Comment: @StefanoPotter can you give an example of what the cartesian list should look like for a folder with the following files?

files_dir/
    test_file1.txt
    test_file2.txt

Comment: if I am understanding correctly the lists would be like this `(['test_file1.txt', 'test_file2.txt'], ['test_file2.txt', test_file1.txt'])`

Answer (score 1):

[glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) supports multiple wildcards, so you can probably accomplish your cartesian product by doing the following:

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join
from itertools import product

BASE_PATH = 'C:\pathway'
all_files = glob(join(BASE_PATH, '*', '*.csv')) # C:\pathway\*\*.csv
result = list(product(all_files, all_files))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) (emphasis mine):

> *pathname* can be either absolute (like `/usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile`) or relative (like `../../Tools/*/*.gif`), and can contain shell-style **wildcards**

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it up into modular components will help reason about similar code in the future:

```
def flatFolders(rootPath):
    '''
        Given a root path (folder) containing deeply nested folders,
        returns a dictionary {folder1:[files of folder1], 
                              folder2:[files of folder2], ...}
    '''
    foldersToFiles = {}
    ...:  # you can use recursions here, or os.walk(rootPath)
        path = ...
        files = ...
        folders[path] = files
    return foldersToFiles

def cartesianSelfProduct(lst):
    '''
        cartesianSelfProduct([1,2,3]) ->
          [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
    '''
    return [(x,y) for x in lst for y in lst]

def flatFolderPairs(rootPath):
    foldersToFiles = flatFolders(rootPath)
    return {folder:cartesianSelfProduct(files) for folder,files in foldersToFiles}
```